# remove border-bottom nth-child of <span> inside <li>

Tags: html, css

I want to set `border-bottom: none;` to the second, fourth and sixth span and so on.

Why doesn't something like:

```
.smallnav-item span:nth-child(2n+2){border-bottom: none;}
```

work ?

```css
.smallnav-item span {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8d3e0;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.smallnav-item {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="smallnav-item">
    <span><a href="#" class="skolv-smallnav-item-link">one</a></span></li>

  <li class="smallnav-item"><span><a href="#" class="skolv-smallnav-item- 
    link">two</a></span></li>

  <li class="smallnav-item"><span><a href="#" class="skolv-smallnav-item- 
  link">three</a></span></li>

  <li class="smallnav-item"><span><a href="#" class="skolv-smallnav-item- 
  link">four</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

.........

Comment: Because every single one of those spans is the first, last and only child of its parent LI …

Comment: Of course, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case a single `<span>` element is placed in a `<li>` element. So the `:nth-child` is not working on the `<span>` element, but you can use the `:nth-child` on the `<li>` element instead.

So you can use the following CSS instead:

```
ul li.smallnav-item:nth-child(even) span {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

So your solution can look like the following:

```css
.smallnav-item span {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8d3e0;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
}

.smallnav-item {
    list-style: none;
}
ul li.smallnav-item:nth-child(even) span {border-bottom:none;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="smallnav-item">
        <span><a href="#" class="skolv-smallnav-item-link">one</a></span></li>
    <li class="smallnav-item"><span><a href="#" class="skolv-smallnav-item- 
    link">two</a></span></li>
  <li class="smallnav-item"><span><a href="#" class="skolv-smallnav-item- 
  link">three</a></span></li>
  <li class="smallnav-item"><span><a href="#" class="skolv-smallnav-item- 
  link">four</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
.smallnav-item span {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8d3e0;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
}
.smallnav-item {
    list-style: none;
}
.smallnav-item:nth-child(even) span {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="smallnav-item">
        <span>
            <a href="#" class="skolv-smallnav-item-link">one</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="smallnav-item">
        <span>
            <a href="#" class="skolv-smallnav-item- 
    link">two</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="smallnav-item">
        <span>
            <a href="#" class="skolv-smallnav-item- 
  link">three</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="smallnav-item">
        <span>
            <a href="#" class="skolv-smallnav-item- 
  link">four</a>
        </span>
    </li>    

</ul>
```